# Can a warlock with Book of Ancient Secrets scribe a known spell into a scroll, replace the spell with a new one, and still be able to cast it?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, rituals, eldritch-invocations

I am playing a 3/3 Divine Soul sorcerer/Hexblade warlock, and have just chosen the Pact of the Tome, along with the Book of Ancient Secrets.

I have found a spellbook with Identify, which I am now transcribing into the book. I also have Unseen Servant as a known spell. I create a scroll, using the Arcana skill. And then use the scroll to transcribe the Unseen Servant spell to the Book. The Scroll is destroyed in the process. So far, so good.

I then replace Unseen Servant with Charm Person on my list of known spells.

Can I still cast the Unseen Servant as a ritual from the book?

Can I cast the Unseen Servant as a spell, using the book and a spell slot? This question arises from the interpretation from the text "You can't cast the spells except as rituals, **unless you've learned them by some other means**.

If this is possible, it basically means I have an external memory extension, that when held, allows me access to cast any of the entries as a ritual.

**And** cast the spells that previously were known spells from my spell list that has been transcribed into the book, as spells, using spell slots.

Comment: Related: "[Are the Book of Ancient Secrets level One ritual spells automatically capped at Two?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/126003)" and "[Can a Warlock with the Book of Ancient Secrets invocation add unintelligible spell scrolls to their book?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/128059)"

Comment: Hello Havenmaker, welcome to RPG.SE. Remember to check out the [tour] and [help] some time.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Any spell in your Book of Ancient Secrets can be cast as a ritual. A spell in your Book of Ancient Secrets can only be cast using a spell slot if you also currently know the spell

The Book of Ancient Secrets states:

> [...] You can’t cast the spells except as rituals, unless you’ve learned them by some other means. [...]

What this means is that a spell contained within your book can be cast only as a ritual *unless* you already know the spell. Imagine this clause were not here, that would mean that adding a spell into your book would *remove* the ability to cast it normally. The clause is here is to prevent such a thing from occurring.

You can add *unseen servant* into your book because the feature states:

> On your adventures, you can add other ritual spells to your Book of Shadows. [...]

This is also gone over in the following questions:

- [Are the Book of Ancient Secrets level One ritual spells automatically capped at Two?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/126003)
- [Can a Warlock with the Book of Ancient Secrets invocation add unintelligible spell scrolls to their book?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/128059)

Thus we've established that you can add *unseen servant* into your book and can cast it as either a ritual or using a spell slot, because you also currently know the spell. If you were to remove *unseen servant* from your spells known list, the clause allowing you to cast it normally would no longer apply; replacing *unseen servant* with another spell means you are no longer able to cast it using a spell slot.

---

One could argue that after unlearning the spell you still *knew* it and so it is a spell "you have learned" but I believe this goes directly against the intent of the feature. The book is not meant to effectively add spells to your "spells known" in this way; it allows you to add the *ritual-casting* version of a spell, not a spell-slot-consuming version.

I believe that "unless you've learned them by some other means" does not apply to spells that you knew at any point in your life and no longer know; it applies only to spells that you currently know.

Comment: That clears it up. 

My confusion was from that phrase, and what it applies to. It makes sense, and I always assumed that was the intent. However, I think the text needs improvement, to be more unambiguous.

Comment: @haven For all I know it's no even ambiguous and there's some sort of English prescriptive grammar rule that dictates how the tense shift doesn't exist or something. Or rather, the text says: "You can't cast (present tense) the spells except as rituals, unless you've learned (what tense is this?) them by some other means." There may be some sort of thing I simply don't know where "you've learned" is using the actual *verb* to have instead of the auxillary verb to have.

Comment: Pretty sure the "having learned" objection still holds as of RAW. I agree that it's definitely not RAI, though.